# How to convert list of pixel into image using python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, python-imaging-library, numpy-ndarray

I want to change specific pixel value in whole image.I have converted image into List using img.getdata() function.now after processing i want to convert that list into image format.please suggest me if you know any way to do so.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('test.jpg','r')
pix=list(img.getdata())
for i in pix:
    if i ==(254,0,0):
        print("found",i)
        pi=np.array(pix)
        pi=Image.fromarray(pi)
        cv2.imshow("img",pi)
```

Error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\pixels.py", line 19, in <module>
    cv2.imshow("img",pi)
TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'mat'
```

i have tried some other way also but not able to see image.

Comment: Why are you mixing PIL and OpenCV, you will confuse yourself! Why are you treating an image as a list and processing pixels in a `for` loop? That will be horribly slow and hard to debug - look at some other PIL/OpenCV questions on Stack Overflow and start thinking about using Numpy or OpenCV vectorised operations.

Comment: Also, remember JPEG is **lossy** so you are probably going wrong if you are looking for a specific RGB(254,0,0) value, because JPEG can and **WILL** change your values when you write to a file. If your values are that specific you need to use PNG or another lossless format.

Comment: Try replacing your last line with `pi.show()` - you can't display a PIL Image with OpenCV which expects a Numpy array.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thank you, i will try but for the moment can u tell how we can convert list back into image form.

Comment: What do you actually want to do in plain language, no code? E.g. *"I want to change all pixels with RGB(254,0,0) to red and display the result"*

Comment: my aim is to compare two image if color order is changed it should show wrong image and if color order match it should show correct image.in shot there are small box of some color in  sequence and i have to compare it with test image

Comment: @MarkSetchell i am new to python so i am trying some funny projects.so can you suggest me any method how can i do it

Comment: BTW: to check pixel in numpy array `if (np.array(img) == (254,0,0)).any():`. As for comparing images - what if you compare full images ? Pillow can compare `img1 == img2` ? If you want to find small element on other image then maybe you need [template matching in OpenCV](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html)

Comment: Can you post sample input and expected output images?

Comment: OP probably can't post images with current reputation, so maybe an upvote of the question is an idea...

Comment: @Alderven color sequence img1: red green blue  img2: blue green red i want to show result i.e image2 color sequence are not match to image1.

Comment: with `PIL` you can compare full image using `img1 == img2` and if they have channels in different order then they will be different. If you convert to numpy array then you can compare regions `(img[y1:y2,x1:x2] == img[y3:y4,x3:x4]).all(axis=2).all()`

Answer (score 2):

This should help:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import cv2

# Open an image
im = cv2.imread('image.png')

# Count RGB(254,0 ,0) pixels
sought = [254,0,0]
total  = np.count_nonzero(np.all(im==sought,axis=2))
print(f'Total before: {total}')

# Draw a rectangle 10x10 that colour
im[0:10,0:10] = sought

# Count pixels that colour
total  = np.count_nonzero(np.all(im==sought,axis=2))
print(f'Total after: {total}')

# Save
cv2.imwrite('result.png',im)
```

[image]

[image]

**Sample Output**

```
Total before: 0
Total after: 100
```

Comment: thank you it work.but you did not get my question.i want to compare two images.which have sequence of color

Comment: You need to do some work on your question so it is clear what you are trying to do. Your code shows you want to know if there is a pixel with RGB(254,0,0) in your image, so if you count the number of pixels with RGB(254,0,0) and it is greater than zero, you will have your answer, surely? If not, please clarify your question and show your images and what you are looking for.